# Alt-tab does not show window switcher when in fullscreen mode

Tags: 16.04, unity, window, fullscreen

I am not yet sure this happens *always*, but at least now it is consistent. Whenever I am in fullscreen mode (either in chromium or in evince, but not in the terminal, for example), pressing `alt-tab` does not show the window switcher, but *does* switch window as if it appeared.

This is a brand new Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell latitude.

Any idea? Debugging I can make in order to figure out what is the cause?

Comment: this happens to me with emacs in fullscreen mode, and with document viewer in presentation mode.